# C# interop: the last fields of my class arrive null-ed out on the C++ side

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I just cannot figure this one out by myself, so I'm wondering if anyone with more Interop experience can spot what am I doing wrong?

The strange behavior that I'm experiencing is that on the C++ side the NumInputShifts field is set to 0 and InputShifts to null, in spite of the fact that they are both properly initialized on the C# side.

Thanks very much!  eugen

These are the C++ structs:

```
struct ALL_INPUT_DATA
{
    CONFIG_DATA ConfigData;
    LOCATION *Locations; // array of input Location objects
    void *FullJobs; // array of input JobRequest objects, format depends on input version format value (0 - FULL_JOB, >=1 - FULL_JOB_DYN)
    SINGLE_JOB *SingleJobs; // array of input ActivityRequest objects
    RESOURCE *Resources; // array of SchedulingResource objects
    ROUTING *Routes; // array of Route objects
    BUFFER_ELEMENT *BufferElements; // array of BufferBetweenActivities objects
    PENALTY_CURVE *PenaltyCurves; // array of PenaltyCalculationCurve objects
    INPUT_SCHEDULE_DATA InputScheduleData;
    int NumWindowSets;
    int *NumWinArray; // array in which every entry is a number of window in set
    TIME_WINDOW *AllWindows; // size of this array - sum(NumWinArray) - sets of windows to be used for pickup and delivery
    int NumInputShifts; // 
    INPUT_SHIFTS *InputShifts; // array of allowed shift patterns - Gozen only for now
};

struct INPUT_SCHEDULE_DATA
{
    int NumResSchedules; // number of input resource schedules
    RES_SCHEDULE *ResSchedules; // array of resource schedule containing scheduled leg activities 
    int NumRelocations;
    RELOCATION *AllRelocations; // array of relocation objects
};
```

And their equivalent C# classes:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class ALL_INPUT_DATA : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Config data
        /// </summary>
        public CONFIG_DATA ConfigData;

        /// <summary>
        /// LOCATION*
        /// array of input Location objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr Locations;

        /// <summary>
        /// FULL_JOB *
        /// array of input JobRequest objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr FullJobs;

        /// <summary>
        /// SINGLE_JOB *
        /// array of input ActivityRequest objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr SingleJobs;

        /// <summary>
        /// RESOURCE *
        /// array of SchedulingResource objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr Resources;

        /// <summary>
        /// ROUTING *
        /// array of Route objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr Routes;

        /// <summary>
        /// BUFFER_ELEMENT *
        /// array of BufferBetweenActivities objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr BufferElements;

        /// <summary>
        /// PENALTY_CURVE *
        /// array of PenaltyCalculationCurve objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr PenaltyCurves;

        public INPUT_SCHEDULE_DATA InputScheduleData;

        public int NumWindowSets;
        public IntPtr NumWinArray; // array in which every entry is a number of window in set
        public IntPtr AllWindows; // size of this array - sum(NumWinArray) - sets of windows to be used for pickup and delivery

        public int NumInputShifts; 
        public IntPtr InputShifts; // array of allowed shift patterns - Gozen only for now
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct INPUT_SCHEDULE_DATA : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// number of input resource schedules
        /// </summary>
        public int NumResSchedules;

        /// <summary>
        /// RES_SCHEDULE *ResSchedules; - array of resource schedule containing scheduled leg activities 
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr ResSchedules;

        /// <summary>
        /// number of relocations
        /// </summary>
        public int NumRelocations;

        /// <summary>
        /// RELOCATION *AllRelocations; - array of relocation objects
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr AllRelocations;
    }
```

The C++ method's signature is:

```
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        public delegate void ErrorLogger(string error);
        private delegate int OptimizeG_Type(IntPtr pInputData, IntPtr pOutData, ErrorLogger errorLogger);
```

respectively

```
int OptimizeG(ALL_INPUT_DATA *pInputData, ALL_OUTPUT_DATA *pOutData, void (*LogFunc)(const char*))
```

This is the code that creates the pInputData pointer:

```
        public static IntPtr GetInputDataPtr(ALL_INPUT_DATA inputData)
        {
            var ret = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ALL_INPUT_DATA)));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(inputData, ret, true);

            return ret;
        }
```

I did verify on the C# side that the data in pInputData is set up properly before making the Interop call.

```
        var testData = Marshal.PtrToStructure<ALL_INPUT_DATA>(pInputData);
```

Comment: Why don't you declare ALL_INPUT_DATA as a struct? You could also declare pInputData just as `ALL_INPUT_DATA` (instead of IntPtr) if it's a class, or `ref ALL_INPUT_DATA` if it's a struct.

Comment: Thanks very much Simon!  Let me try taking the C# struct route, see where I get with it.

I cannot go the route of `ref ALL_INPUT_DATA` because we use the Win32 LoadLibraryEx,... procedure in order to allow the customer to pick different DLL files depending on their request.

Comment: @SimonMourier turning ALL_INPUT_DATA into a `struct` made no difference :-(  Please note that CONFIG_DATA and INPUT_SCHEDULE_DATA are already `struct`.  It appears that the interop data transfer stops to a halt after it passes the InputScheduleData field.  The good news is that I have a brand new entry into the "Weird Behaviors' Gallery": I moved the InputScheduleData to be the last element in the `struct` on both sides and marshalling works now perfectly.  Could someone please enlighten us on what is going on here?

Comment: The code you show is obviously not complete and is not sufficient to demonstrate the problem. Post a reproducing code somewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out.  As the C#-side `struct INPUT_SCHEDULE_DATA` is implementing the `IDisposable` interface, it had an _alreadyDisposed field which brought it to the size of 40 bytes.  The C-side equivalent struct is only 32 bytes.  As such, the marshaling into C's `struct ALL_INPUT_DATA` was pushing over all bits that were following the `INPUT_SCHEDULE_DATA InputScheduleData;` field by 8 bytes.